# Salesforce oauth authorization flows: can we skip login screen, automatically attempt SSO through an Auth Provider?

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce, single-sign-on

I attempted to ask this question before, but after some research, I have distilled down and reworded the question a bit better.

Two things about our set up:

1. We have a Connected App for pulling data from the chatter_api.
2. We have an Auth Provider (OIDC) in Salesforce.

During our app's oauth authorize flow, if the user is not logged into Salesforce, a login screen is presented. That's expected behavior, of course, but we want to be seamless and skip the login if possible.

In our scenario, most of the time, the Salesforce user session will not yet exist. But the user WILL be logged in at our Auth Provider. Login screen even shows "Or log in using: <our Auth Provider>". My question is, can we somehow configure our authorization flow to automatically attempt SSO and skip the login screen (assuming successful SSO)? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it in another area,not in connected app. Setup->My Domain, scroll down to login options and leave only the SSO checkbook.

From now on navigating your branded login page (mycompany.my.salesforce.com) should auto redirect you to your Auth provider (and if you have valid session - back to sf). You'll still be able to use sf username & password on generic login page (unless you blocked it in My Domain) and by "hacking" your way to the mycompany.my.salesforce.com?login url

Comment: That is a good start; I got it to work, but might be a little restrictive for us (and other partners of ours that use our Connected App and set up our Auth Provider in their own SF orgs).

Comment: Another idea we've had is to somehow automatically/invisibly do SSO at SF in the background (or redirect back to our app after doing SSO), but we are novices at SF and haven't seen a way to do that. Do you know of any options there, @eyescream?

Comment: I sense some conflicting business requirements, on 1 hand you want seamless (and 1-click away is not enough) but you also want to provide options for multiple login methods? You might be able to construct login link from your app to SF. Consider asking on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ too. Your SF account exec/partner might be able to set a session up with SF internal experts too, something like accelerators program https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000322523&type=1

Comment: I think you're right about conflicting business requests/requirements. Though, I think some kind of "use this auth method" parameter *could* be a useful feature, albeit perhaps a bit niche. Thank you for you insights!